# Partition list with sentinel values

Tags: java, collections

I have an array list with values such as

```
{ "november", "a","b","c","d", "december", "i","j","k", "april", "g","h" }
```

What is the best way to split it so i can have different arrays based on months.for example

```
List<String> novemberArray={"a","b","c","d"}
```

and

```
List<String> decemberArray={"i","j","k"}`
```

etc..

I am getting this list from parsing an html page with Jsoup.

```
Elements tableRowElements = tableElements.select(":not(thead) tr");
for (int i = 0; i < tableRowElements.size(); i++) {
  Element row = tableRowElements.get(i);
  System.out.println("row : " );
  Elements rowItems = row.select("tr");
  for (int j = 1; j < rowItems.size(); j++) {
    System.out.println(rowItems.get(j).text());
    myList.add(rowItems.get(j).text());
  }
}
```

myList has the values of `{ "november", "a","b","c","d", "december", "i","j","k", "april", "g","h" }`
List is dynamic and i dont have any control on the positions in the list. Using sub indexes will not help because they change frequently.

Comment: Can you post some code showing your current approach?

Comment: If you have a control over the array you're getting, then i **strongly** suggest you to change approch, to more detailed inteface.
One way would be { "November=a,b,c,d;December=i,j,k" } and so on. It will help you split your array more clearly and be more readable.

Comment: imho best what you can do is replace map with list where it is initially created

Answer (score 1):

One way is to 
**find the start and the end Index** and use [subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList%28int,%20int%29) to get a view of a portion of the original list.

From the API:

> Returns a view of the portion of this list between the specified
>   fromIndex, inclusive, and toIndex, exclusive. (If fromIndex and
>   toIndex are equal, the returned list is empty.) The returned list is
>   backed by this list, so non-structural changes in the returned list
>   are reflected in this list, and vice-versa. The returned list supports
>   all of the optional list operations supported by this list.

Comment: i dont think positions for month name must be constant

Comment: @HussainAkhtarWahid Sure, I said, `find the start and the end distance.` SO the concept will be to implement a logic to see if it is of any months and then use the subList

Answer (score 1):

So you have an `ArrayList` containing data (`"a"`, `"b"`, ect.) and *also* sentinel values(`"november"`, etc.)?   Orel Eraki's comment is spot on, you're asking for trouble dealing with data like this.  If you can, you'll find a lot less pain avoiding this methodology entirely.

But, assuming you can't change it, here's how you can get away with it.  I use a [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) [Multimap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html), and I strongly recommend you do too, but you can substitute in a `HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>` with just a little extra boilerplate.

```
public ListMultimap<String,String> removeSentinels(List<String> ls,
                                                   Set<String> sentinels) {
  String currentSentinel = null;
  ArrayListMultimap<String,String> map = ArrayListMultimap.create();
  for(String s : ls) {
    if(sentinels.contains(s)) {
      currentSentinel = s;
    } else {
      /*
      Note if the list doesn't start with a sentinel value, it will put items in the
      null entry.  You could instead do a null check here and raise an exception, or
      use an ImmutableListMultimap which forbids null keys or values.
      */
      map.put(currentSentinel, s);
    }
  }
  return map;
}
```

You can then get the elements with `List<String> novemberList = map.get("november");` and so on.

---

Your JSoup example explains the underlying conceptual problem.  You are taking 2D table data and reading it into a 1D list.  The same behavior I describe above can be used to more cleanly parse this table data into a `Multimap` from the get-go, avoiding the need to re-parse later (alternatively, Guava also offers a [`Table`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Table.html) interface, but that's probably overkill for your use-case):

```
public ListMultimap<String,String> tableToMap(Document doc) {
  Elements trElems = doc.select(":not(thead) tr");
  ArrayListMultimap<String,String> map = ArrayListMultimap.create();
  for(Element tr : trElems) {
    // I assume you meant td, a <tr> shouldn't contain <tr>'s
    Elements tdElems = tr.select("td");
    String month = tdElems.get(1).text(); // You skip index 0, presumably intentionally
    for(int i = 2; i < tdElems.size(); i++) {
      map.put(month, tdElems.get(i).text());
    }
  }
  return map;
}
```

Comment: Thankyou so much. Guava and your suggestion worked like a charm. Awesome

Comment: Glad I could help, Guava's got a lot of very cool functionality, it's worth the time to fully explore their docs.

Answer (score 0):

Create a map of String to List to hold months as Keys and list of your a,b,c etc as values.

Loop through the ArrayList and check each entry against a list or set of month Strings ("January","February",...), each time you encounter a positive match then set a 'currentMonth' variable to the matching month and add/update the corresponding list entry in the Map for each of the following non-month variables.

Pseudo Code:

```
If (entry is month) {
    currentMonth = entry;
} else {
    List entries = monthMap.get(currentMonth) == null ? new ArrayList<>() : monthMap.get(currentMonth)
    entries.add(entry)
    monthMap.put(currentMonth, entries)
}
```

Comment: No need to re-put the list into the map if it was already there.

Comment: Yes, just handling the case where it wasn't already there, for completeness.

Answer (score -1):

here is layman approach

```
import java.util.*;

public class One {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String[] inputArray = new String[]{ "november", "a","b","c","d","december", "i","j","k","april", "g","h"};
        List<String> monthNames = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> monthNamesOutput = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> alphabetsOutput = new ArrayList<String>();
        monthNames.add("january");
        monthNames.add("february");
        monthNames.add("march");
        monthNames.add("april");
        monthNames.add("may");
        monthNames.add("june");
        monthNames.add("july");
        monthNames.add("august");
        monthNames.add("september");
        monthNames.add("october");
        monthNames.add("november");
        monthNames.add("december");
        for(String temp:inputArray)
        {
            if(monthNames.contains(temp))
            {
                monthNamesOutput.add(temp);
            }
            else
            {
                alphabetsOutput.add(temp);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(monthNamesOutput);
        System.out.println(alphabetsOutput);
    }
}
```

Comment: -1: doing contains checks against a `List` is wasteful.  Use a `Set` instead.

Comment: i used the list because i was uncertain whether the output array must have month names only once or is possible to get repeated

Comment: I'm referring to your `monthNames` list.  You're doing an O(n) search against that list for every item in the list, netting you O(n^2) performance.